# How to make the margin-left of one div equal the margin-left of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make the `margin-left` of `<div id="3">` equal to the `margin-left` of `<div id="1">` and use bootstrap class container.

Comment: post the code inside the question

Comment: don`t confuse post your exact code

Answer (score -1):

Check [Bootstrap Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) for the correct use of its grid system.
You can use `offset-` classes.